# Insert Data into SQL Table

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, insert

The Data in my DataTable is like

```
ID ContactName1  Designation1 ContactName2 Designation2
1  A             dummy        B            sam
```

The Table structure of my Table is

```
ID ContactName Designation
```

I am passing the values in the stored procedure as:

```
@ContactName1
@Designation1

@ContactName2
@Designation2
```

I want a single insert statement to insert the records.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your ID primary key is set on auto-increment, and your table has three fields:

```
INSERT INTO DataTable (ContactName, Designation) VALUES 
    (@ContactName1, @Designation1), 
    (@ContactName2, @Designation2);
```

As per the actual ID, if you don't have it on auto-increment, which judging from the comment on Ivan's response, you don't, you could actually get it using the MAX() statement:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) AS max_id FROM DataTable
```

Comment: You can directly insert the SELECT statement in the INSERT statement if you need to. Also, it should be MAX(ID)+1 IMHO.

Comment: Oh yeah, as Cd-MaN mentions you definitely have to increment the MAX statement after retrieving it.  However, I would increment it once you get it back from the database, instead of doing it directly in the query.  I find these operations on the database tend to be slow.

Comment: This syntax is not supported in SQL Server prior to 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Given that it is in a stored procedure, why do you care whether it is one or two INSERT statements?  Clearly, two statements is trivial.

Some DBMS allow you to list multiple values clauses in a single INSERT (@Ivan suggests this):

```
INSERT INTO Table(ID, ContactName, Designation)
    VALUES(1, @ContactName1, @Designation1)
    VALUES(1, @ContactName2, @Designation2);
```

I'm not certain whether a comma is needed between the values lists.  I'm also not clear whether the two records in Table are allowed to have the same ID, nor how the ID is determined - that is probably some auto-increment stuff, and different DBMS do that differently too.

If your DBMS does not support multiple VALUES clauses in a single INSERT statement, then you will be best off accepting two INSERT statements.  If atomicity is an issue, you can consider transactions - though if this is just a part of a bigger transaction, ROLLBACK on error, in particular, would be a problem.  If your DBMS supports SAVEPOINTS, then the procedure could establish a savepoint on entry, and commit or rollback to the savepoint on exit.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO TABLENAME VALUES(GIVE VALUE ACCORDING TO NUMBER AND ORDER SEPARATED BY COMMA)

EX:-

`INSERT INTO TABLENAME VALUES(1,'INDIA')`

HERE IS TWO COLUMN S.N. & COUNTRY